# Custom Cell - Change color of background and button in custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a custom cell that I have made in the iterfacebuilder and connected to my .h file.

And then in my CustomCell.m file I have

```
@implementation TwoMealsTableViewCell

@synthesize dayLabel, firstMealBtn, secondMealBtn, indexPath;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    dayLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

    if (self) {

        dayLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];


    }

    return self;
}


- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

And I have the cell all set up in the tableview, and I see the buttons, and labels, but I don't see the color change?

Why is this.

Thanks for the help in advance!!!

Comment: Is the label connected in your xib/storyboard to appropriate outlet?

Comment: Is that `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method even called? Probably not for a custom cell created through IB.

Comment: @AsifAsif yes the label is connected

Comment: @rmaddy okay then what method would I use?

Comment: initWithCoder is called for cells created in the storyboard, but that's too early to get your outlets. Use awakeFromNib, the outlets are set by the time that's called..

Comment: @rdelmar thanks again lol. can I also set the height of the cell in there?

Comment: No, the table view controls the height of the cells. Do you need different heights, or are they all the same?

Comment: @rdelmar I need different heights

Comment: Then you should implement tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: in your table view controller.

Comment: @rdelmar can I set the color of the cell in awakeFromNib method or does that have to be done in the cell for row method

Comment: It depends on whether they're all going to be the same color. Since the cell is reused, if you have different colors in different rows, then you have to do it in cellForRow or willDisplayCell.

Comment: @rdelmar all the cells will be the same color.

Comment: You can do it in awakeFromNib then, if I'm remembering correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will change the cell color

```
dayLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```